# AngularJS controller is not executing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.
I just tried it with Code School.
Here is my code. Controller not executing.
Where is the my mistake?

Here is the HTML file

```
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
    <h2> $ {{store.product.price}} </h2>
    <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js file

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);
  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.product = gem;
  });

  var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .',
  }
})();
```

Comment: your `StoreController` is empty, but your HTML is expecting an object called `product` to be defined there.

Comment: I second @Claies... That should be the problem.

Comment: ok, with the modified controller, you should be getting an output.  What is actually occurring? are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: I am getting this error "Error: Argument 'StoreController as store' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: works fine in the plunker I made.... http://plnkr.co/edit/dm5u7MSfs0XuuvI6WqST?p=preview.  Which version of Angular are you using? you need 1.2 or higher to use the "controller as" syntax

Comment: yes i think it's version problem. thanks a lot. I updated angularJS version. Now works fine.

Comment: @Claies You should post an answer with that so that OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will invoke StoreController with a $scope object.
$scope is the application object (the owner of application variables and functions).

**In app.js:**

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);
  app.controller('StoreController', function($scope){
    $scope.product = gem;
  });

  var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .',
  }
})();
```

**In html:**

```
 <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
    <h2> $ {{product.price}} </h2>
    <p> {{product.description}} </p>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $scope inside controller,then only it will works

```
  (function(){
  var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);
  app.controller('StoreController', function($scope){
    $scope.product = gem;
  });

  var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .',
  }
})();
```